# How to store and read millions of records in Azure with secondary indexing

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-table-storage

I need to store tens of millions of records in Azure. I need to be able to sort them by insert date in descending order. Finally, I need to issue `where` clauses on 3 fields.

```
public class Record
{
   public DateTime CreatedOn {get; set;}
   public string Filter1 {get; set;}
   public string Filter2 {get; set;}
   public bool Filter3 {get; set;}
}
```

I believe Azure Table Storage does not support secondary indexes, so I'm considering CosmosDB. The problem is each logical partition on CosmosDB is limited to 20 GBs. I can't dump everything in a single partition. I'm thinking of slicing data horizontally based on the `CreatedOn` field (`dd/mm/yyyy` without the time component). This helps me distribute the data, but I'm stuck with the query part to read it back.

The data is user generated; thus, I have no idea what values `CreatedOn` will be assigned. If I partition on `CreatedOn`, how can I make my query smart so that I know what the next partition key is when I reach the end of the previous partition?

Example:

Record1 CreatedOn => **5/28/2020**

Record2 CreatedOn => 5/28/2020

Record3 CreatedOn => **5/22/2020**

Record4 CreatedOn => **5/10/2020**

There could be a large gap between dates, so I don't want to brute force the next partition by scanning the range day by day.

**Regarding queries:**

`Filter1` and `Filter2` can have 5 and 12 different values respectively. `Filter3` is just a boolean.

A sample query would look like:

```
select top 20 from record 
where Filter1 = 'Value1' and Filter2 = 'Value2' and Filter3 = false 
order by CreatedOn desc
```

Another sample query is the same as above without `Filter2`.

```
select top 20 from record 
where Filter1 = 'Value1' and Filter3 = false 
order by CreatedOn desc
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and include some of the queries you would be writing? Also, if I understand correctly you would like to see the data in descending order based on CreatedOn field. Right?

Comment: Updated. Correct. The data needs to be sorted in descending order of creation time. I will read up to a certain number of records and use a continuation token to keep going.

Comment: With Azure Storage Tables what I had done is created the partition key based on reverse ticks `(DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks - CreatedOn.Ticks).ToString("d20")`. That way the records are prepended so that you always get latest records first without specifying any order by clause (which is not supported in any case by table storage).

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to have the ability to filter records. I initially started using ATS but noticed later that it does not support secondary indexes.

Comment: You're correct about lack of secondary indexes. I have learned to live without them :). I am absolutely in love with Table Storage :P. You could specify the filter criteria in ATS as well. Where ATS would falter badly is when you don't include the partition key in your query. As long as you include partition key in the query (rather filter criteria), you should be fine.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know the partition keys. If PK1 has 1 record and PK2 has 19 records and I need to return 20 records, I need to know both of those partition keys. As I said, the data is user generated and I have no control over the creation dates.

Comment: Is it possible to use any other property as the PK? It could be a existing property or a new property?

Comment: @ravitella I'm open to suggestions as long as I could sort data by insert time.

Answer (score 0):

Use Cosmos SQL API. You can use Order by to sort on query. 
All the fields are indexed by default. You can customize the indexing policy to include composite indices to make queries more efficient.

Pick a PK which will have a wide range of possible values to spread the request unit (RU) consumption and data storage evenly across all logical partitions evenly. Also, you should know the PK value for majority of your queries. You will use it in you where clause so that the query engine will only query specific partitions where the data of interest resides.

In you case what should be that PK property?

```
public class Record
{
   public DateTime CreatedOn {get; set;}
   public string Filter1 {get; set;}
   public string Filter2 {get; set;}
   public bool Filter3 {get; set;}
}
```

"CreatedOn" is not a good choice. First, like you mentioned you would not know its value during query time, so you will have to always do cross partition queries. Second, all your writes for a given day will go to the same partition resulting in hot partition which will result in rate-limiting and in inefficient use of the provisioned throughput, and higher costs.

Do any of the other properties help the cause? Maybe you must create another property. Maybe UserID , I am just making one up since I don’t know the context.

```
public class Record
{
   public DateTime CreatedOn {get; set;}
   public string Filter1 {get; set;}
   public string Filter2 {get; set;}
   public bool Filter3 {get; set;}
   public string UserID {get; set;}
}
```

Now you can query

```
select top 20 from record 
where Filter1 = 'Value1' and Filter2 = 'Value2' and Filter3 = false  and UserID = 'somevalue' order by CreatedOn desc
```